# How to fix quota limit error on Foursquare?

Tags: foursquare

Every day when I'm using Foursquare, after half an hour of usage I've got the error in my web browser:

> Quota exceeded

and after that every operation which I make it's doing time out with the message:

> We’re having trouble connecting. Try that again in a second.

E.g. when trying to add the list (after some time it works fine):

[image: Quota exceeded on foursquare]

It's very annoying.

I've read about some rate-limit for apps which are using API ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196329/api-quota-exceeded), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048300/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-foursquare-venue-rate-limit-without-actually-costing) and [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits)) and you can even increase it, but I never heard about the limits for the web browser usage.

Why this is happening? Is there any solution to deal with such a problem without creating multiple accounts?

Comment: This is the actual `foursquare.com` website?!

Comment: @w3d Yes, it happens on regular website with regular usage. Added screenshot for clarification, but it's not only specific for creating a list, but many operations such as adding the places into the lists, etc.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on their website :/ It appears like they won't fix it.

Comment: well, fortunately alternatives to that kind of poor service exist.. I know they don't care about a single user but one by one.. deleted the account and moved on.